How to scale Profile Curve along specific axis with Geo Nodes?
I would like to ask how I can scale the profile of my curve on specific axis. For example for some curves I want the tip to have a bigger X scale than the root. But I can only find articles to change the RADIUS along the curve. Please show me how to get a workaround for the radius input!
Thanks in advance.



Closed as a duplicate - if you disagree this is a duplicate, please [Edit] your post explaining how your situation is different / where you struggle in applying the linked setup for your case.
